# Calculate the start date and end date of week number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using the following formulas to obtain the start date and end date of the week number, given the week number and the year:

Start of week:`=MAX(DATE(A2,1,1),DATE(A2,1,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(A2,1,1),2)+(B2-1)*7+1)`

End of week: `=MIN(DATE(A2+1,1,0),DATE(A2,1,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(A2,1,1),2)+B2*7)`

It seems to work well except that week `1` of `2019` begins on `31-12-2018` but my formula for the start date of the week `1` shows it as `01-01-2019`. What is the problem with my formula?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just calculate the `end date` (using your existing formula), and then calculate your `Start Date` by subtracting 6 from that? `=[@EndDate]-6`

Comment: @Zack thanks! Didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

Just subtract 6 from the end date formula

`=(MIN(DATE(A2+1,1,0),DATE(A2,1,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(A2,1,1),2)+B2*7))-6`

Answer (score 0):

As I noted in my comment, the easiest way is just to subtract 6 from your end date. If your data is in a table, your formula would be `=[@EndDate]-6`. Otherwise, it would be something like `=E2-6`.